# Get specific child nodes from firebase in swift 3?

Tags: firebase, swift3, nodes

I am trying to get all the names only from the "user_profies" nodes. But can't seem to get this to return the correct data. It's not returning anything at all.

user_profiles

```
 K0lGHBACNqUa5Yjn233UsZcUMUk1
*        email: "testiphone@gmail.com"      
*        name: "James"
*       
 PMBsHxol4fYxHGb4oPeL7IMdzzS2
*        email: "iphone4@gmail.com"close        
*        name: "Tom"
```

This is what I tried

```
ref.child("user_profiles").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    print("Returned Data \(snapshot)")


}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling this? What are your database rules?

Comment: @JenPerson thanks for your response, I am new to firebase. The rule is to allow authorize users to read and write data. Just dont know how to get retrieve the stored data. Anyhelp would be appreciated